# Restrict Window.SizeToContent to expand only

Tags: wpf, window

Is it somehow possible to restrict [`Window.SizeToContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) to expand the size only?

I have a general window that is dynamically filled with content in a [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx). As it is not known at the beginning how large each TabItem is going to be I cannot precalculate the required size (I only care about height though) to display it all without scrolling.

Enabling `SizeToContent` will automatically adjust the size to the required size whenever the tab is changed. While it’s okay that it only expands when the current view requires more space, I dislike that the window will also shrink when less space is required. Is it possible to restrict the `SizeToContent` behavior to just allow *expansion* of the window size? Or can the behavior be emulated in a different way, while still producing correct results taking the window frames and other components next to the tab control into account?

I tried hooking into different window events to find out where the new size information goes when changing the tab, but the only real useful one on the window, [`OnChildDesiredSizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onchilddesiredsizechanged.aspx), was not producing deterministic results (for some tabs it was called, for others it wasn’t). Do you have any other idea?

Comment: How about simply defining a minimum size?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia As I said, the window is dynamically filled with content. And I actually want to allow the user to resize it and make it smaller. I just want the default size to be “perfect” for the displayed content.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [FrameworkElement.MinHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight.aspx) and [FrameworkElement.MinWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth.aspx) to set the minimum height/width after the `Window` has loaded.

```
public void WindowLoaded()
{
    this.MinHeight = this.ActualHeight;
    this.MinWidth = this.ActualWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried Bobs approach. His answer is the right approach.

In my case the WindowLoaded event fired to early. It fired before the content was rendered.

Therefore I used the "ContentRendered" event and now my window wont shrink if the content size is reduced. If your content may increase its size after the windows is shown for the first time, you could use the "SizeChanged" event.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've used the Binding `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` to `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` in the Window:

```
    x:Name="printWnd"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=printWnd}"
    MinHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=printWnd}"
```